# Grouped sum in nested dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a data structure in this form:

```
{
        "600": {
                "comment": 9,
                "like": 27,
                "unlike": 3,
                "photo_view": 267,
                "post_engagement": 3291,
                "page_engagement": 3318,
                "post_reaction": 3003,
                "post": 12
            },
        "607": {
                "comment": 3,
                "like": 45,
                "photo_view": 264,
                "post_engagement": 3861,
                "page_engagement": 3906,
                "link_click": 6,
                "post_reaction": 3579,
                "post": 9
            }
        }
```

There can be any number of items in the dict at top level. I want result like:

```
{
 "comment": 12 #9 + 3,
 "like": 72 #45 + 27
 .......

}
```

NOTE: Some elements might miss one or more keys like `comment` might be missing in second element. How can I get this done using idiomatic python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the nested dicts to [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) objects and use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#sum) to add them together:

```
from collections import Counter

d = {
    "600": {
        "comment": 9,
        "like": 27
    },
    "607": {
        "comment": 3,
        "like": 45
    },
    "608": {
        "like": 1
    }
}

print(sum((Counter(v) for v in d.values()), Counter()))
```

Output:

```
Counter({'like': 73, 'comment': 12})
```

If you want the result as `dict` instead of `Counter` you can convert the result back to `dict`:

```
print(dict(sum((Counter(v) for v in d.values()), Counter())))
```

Output:

```
{'comment': 12, 'like': 73}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
myVal={'607': {'comment': 3, 'page_engagement': 3906, 'like': 45, 'link_click': 6, 'post_reaction': 3579, 'post': 9, 'photo_view': 264, 'post_engagement': 3861}, '600': {'comment': 9, 'page_engagement': 3318, 'like': 27, 'unlike': 3, 'post_reaction': 3003, 'post': 12, 'photo_view': 267, 'post_engagement': 3291}}
res={}
for l in [val for key,val in myVal.iteritems()]:
    for d,c in l.iteritems():
        res[d]=c if d not in res.keys() else res[d]+c

print res
#{'comment': 12, 'like': 72, 'unlike': 3, 'photo_view': 531, 'post_engagement': 7152, 'page_engagement': 7224, 'link_click': 6, 'post_reaction': 6582, 'post': 21}
#Time for execution 0.000068105091
```

usin#g Counter:

```
print(sum((Counter(v) for v in myVal.values()), Counter()))
#Time for execution 0.00473729887596
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping